# Obtain the form and range of a matrix from its null space and left null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

The matrix  has ()  [ 1 0 −1], and () [1 1 1 1] and [ 1 1 −1 −1]. What is the form of matrix  and its range?

I known that the null space is related to columns and left null space is related to the rows, but not how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Is $\{(1,0,-1)\}$ given as a basis for the null space of $A$? (same for $N(A^T)$) Otherwise the statement does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the statement given means the following: let $\{(1,0,-1)\}$ be a *basis* for $N(A)$ and $\{(1,1,1,1), \, (1,1,-1,-1)\}$ be a *basis* for $N(A^T)$.

From the facts given, we get that $A$ must be a $4 \times 3$ matrix.

You may use the fact that the row space $r(A)$ and the null space $N(A)$ are orthogonal complements. So,
$$r(A)=\{(x,y,z) \, | \, (x,y,z) \cdot (1,0,-1)=0\}=\{(x,y,z) \, | \, x=z\}.$$
This shows that
$$r(A)=\text{Span}\left(\{(1,0,1),\, (0,1,0)\}\right).$$
Thus $A$ may look like:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&a\\c&d&c\\s&0&s\\0&t&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now see if you can use the fact that column space $c(A)$ and the left null space $N(A^T)$ are orthogonal complements to get $A$ (by getting more conditions on $a,b,c,d,s,t$).